# Manga about a princess and her fiancee who are killed, and she is reborn as a noble

Tags: story-identification, manga

The main character is a princess that has strong power but one time she is attacked, and she and her fiance get killed but she suddenly woke up as a noble girl (yeah she didn't start from baby but she just woke up in a different body) that seems hated by her family . . . she find her previous fiance but she is prince fiance even he doesn't loves her . . .

Comment: I did my best to spruce this up, but I'm really not certain what is meant by that last sentence...

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is [Her Royal Highness Seems to be Angry](https://www.tokyopop.com/book-catalogue-new-titles/her-royal-highness-seems-to-be-angry-vol-1). It's about a princess with high magic power who dies when her kingdom is invaded and everyone dies. She reincarnates a thousand years later as teenaged Lady Dorossel, but not knowing any of Dorossel's life beforehand so everyone thinks Dorossel is faking returning to a calm personality (she apparently turned into a huge drama queen a couple of years prior and didn't have any magic power).

The fiancee reincarnating is implied, but I have not read this to the point where it is confirmed.